# How to make php function according to the drop down menu list selection without a button

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello I am working with php and I have this drop down menu list code:

```
<form method="POST" >
    <select name="users" id="users">
        <option <?php if(isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == '2') echo "selected='selected'";  ?> value="2">User one</option>
        <option <?php if(isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == '3') echo "selected='selected'";  ?> value="3">User Two</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth"  name="refresh" value="Refresh">
</form>
```

and then there is this php code that starts as follows:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['refresh'])){
        ....
?>
```

Now I want to remove the button from the html and want to make the php code execute automatically when selected from the drop-down list menu. I tried something with javascript but wasnt what I needed it was just printing the value as an alert.

this is the code of javascript i tried

```
var x = document.getElementById('users').selectedIndex; 
var text = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].text;//its a text 
document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML = text;
```

How do i make it to submit the form?

Tried this other javascript but this makes my page stuck on refresh I put this `onchange="fuksion()"` on `<form>`

```
 <script>
      function funksion() {
      document.getElementById("user").submit();
       }
      funksion();
     </script>
```

Comment: PHP is run on the server. If you want something to happen/trigger on the client-side ("_when selected from the drop-down list menu_") you need Javascript. Adjust the Javascript you had to not alert a value but submit the form

Comment: @brombeer this is the code ` var x = document.getElementById('users').selectedIndex;
  var text = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].text;//its a text
  document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML = text;` How do i make it to submit the form?

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, hard to read as you can see. Instead, [edit] your question and post relevant code there. Thanks

Comment: @brombeer i edit it

Comment: Here's how I'd solve this: https://pastebin.com/rqwP3re5 (I'd also use GET instead of POST)

Comment: `getElementById("user")` There is no element with that `id`. And you should submit _the form_, not the `<select>`. (And don't call `funksion();` right after declaring it, let `onchange` do that)

Comment: @brombeer i added the "user"  at the form when i tried this js code

Comment: @brombeer this method makes my page stuck on refresh

Comment: I guess because you run `funksion();` after declaring it. Page is loaded, `funksion();` is executed -> loop

Comment: yes where do i declare that ?

Comment: Did you take a look at my pastebin? It has everything you need.

Comment: @ChrisG Why post this at pastebin and not as an answer?

Comment: @ChrisG Ok, valid reason :)

Comment: @brombeer Not the response I expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an eventlistener (change) to submit the form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <select name="users" id="users">
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == '2') echo "selected";  ?> value="2">User one</option>
    <option <?php if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == '3') echo "selected";  ?> value="3">User Two</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script>
  let usersSelect = document.getElementById('users');
  users.addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.form.submit();
  })
</script>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['users'])) {
  echo "You selected " . $_POST['users'];
}
?>
```

On first load of the page the first option will be selected, so the `change` event will only trigger if you select the second option. To circumvent this, add an "empty" option:

```
<select name="users" id="users">
  <option value="">-- choose one --</option>
  <option <?php if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == '2') echo "selected";  ?> value="2">User one</option>
  <option <?php if (isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == '3') echo "selected";  ?> value="3">User Two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code you will get value on select

form.php  page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery Get Selected Option Value</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select.value").change(function(){
        var selectedValue = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        //alert("You have selected  " + selectedValue);
        
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "query-process.php",
        data: { type: selectedValue }, // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
          alert(data); // show response from the php script.
        }
    });
    });
});
</script>
</head> 
<body>
    <form>
        <label>Select value:</label>
        <select class="value">
             <option <?php if(isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == '2') echo "selected='selected'";  ?> value="2">User one</option>
        <option <?php if(isset($_POST['users']) && $_POST['users'] == '3') echo "selected='selected'";  ?> value="3">User Two</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

query-process.php -->> in this page you will get value by this

```
print_r($_POST['type']);
```

after getting the value, you have to run your SQL query to submit the form to your database and also you can run the query for searching value in the database

Comment: i dont need to get my value shown i need the form to be submited when i select from the drop menu list

Comment: What if OP doesn't want to use jquery?

Comment: ok  i will update the code according to your requirement

Comment: i update my code you can check and get data in query-process.php page and submit your form here

Comment: @brombeer without jQuery and JS it is not possible to make the PHP code execute automatically when selected from the drop-down list menu

Comment: That's only half true. You need JS, but not jQuery

Comment: yes @brombeer I mean jQuery or JS we can use any one from these